# .htaccess rewrite root folder to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Please could I have some help redirecting URLs to a subfolder so that everything in `https://example.com` is rewritten to `https://example.co.uk/subfolder`?

The `.htaccess` file needs to be in `/subfolder`.

Comment: Are the different domains `site1.co.uk` and `site.co.uk` significant? Or should this be the same host? Is there another `.htaccess` file in the `/subfolder`? If so, what does this contain?

Comment: Sorry, they were both supposed to say site1.co.uk. The .htaccess is in the subfolder. I have edited the question to reflect.

Comment: I've updated my answer regarding your update that "The .htaccess file needs to be in /subfolder." - if that is the case then what you are asking is not possible. In order to rewrite the request from the root to the subfolder then the `.htaccess` file _must_ be in the root.

Answer (score 0):

[MrWhite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369434/mrwhite) already gave nearly all the explanation I should have attached to my answer. So, like he already stated in his answer, the *directives* given below should be written into the `.htaccess` file that is located in the folder where `https://site1.co.uk` points to for it to work as you expect.

Here are the directives you can use.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /subfolder/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The first `RewriteCond` will help make sure that the request is not for a file that already exists in the folder that the .htaccess file is located.

The second `RewriteCond` line is similar to the first but this checks for a folder instead. After this line, you can, and probably should, add the `REDIRECT_STATUS` line from [MrWhite's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69354257/13660617). See his answer for the explanation.

The `RewriteRule` line uses Regular Expressions (RegEx) to effect the rewrite. Remember to replace `subfolder` on this line to name of the folder you wish to use and this folder should exist in the same location that the .htaccess file is located, and like already explained, this must be the folder that `https://site1.co.uk` points to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome. Can you edit your answer to provide more detail? Please take a look at the other answer offered on this question as a good example of the level of detail expected on Stack Overflow.

Comment: There are actually a few issues with this solution (all the more reason for an explanation, which could help highlight the problems)... If there isn't an additional `.htaccess` file in the subfolder containing mod_rewrite directives (not stated in the question) and the rewritten request does not map to a file (or directory) then this will result in a rewrite-loop (500 error). This also doesn't rewrite requests for the root directory itself.

Comment: Thanks [Jeremy Caney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3025856/jeremy-caney). I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following in the root `.htaccess` file to rewrite all direct requests to the subfolder.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite all direct requests to the `/subfolder` directory
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^ subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures that only direct requests from the client (as opposed to internally rewritten requests) are rewritten to the `/subfolder` directory (thus avoiding a rewrite loop).

This also means that a direct request for `/subfolder` itself will also be rewritten to the `/subfolder` directory (ie. `/subfolder/subfolder`) - so you can have a sub-subfolder of the same name if you wish (otherwise direct requests for `/subfolder` will result in a 404). That is, unless you have an additional `.htaccess` file in the subfolder that also contains mod_rewrite directives, in which case these directives will be overridden.

---

**UPDATE:** Following your question update that now states the following...

> The `.htaccess` file needs to be in `/subfolder`.

In that case, this is not possible. The `.htaccess` file that rewrites requests to the `/subfolder` *must* be in the document root (the parent directory).

If the `.htaccess` file is in the `/subfolder` itself then it will simply never be processed for requests outside of that subfolder in order to rewrite the request.